# C26451: Arithmetic overflow using operator '+' on a 4 byte value then casting the result to 8 byte value

Tags: c++, hash, overflow, rabin-karp

i am trying to write a program that searches through  a movie script using two different string searching algorithms. However the Warning **C26451: Arithmetic overflow using operator '+' on a 4 byte value then casting the result to 8 byte value** keeps on coming up in the calculate hash part of the rabin karp, is there anyway to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#define d 256
Position rabinkarp(const string& pat, const string& text) {

    int M = pat.size();
    int N = text.size();
    int i, j;
    int p = 0; // hash value for pattern  
    int t = 0; // hash value for txt  
    int h = 1;
int q = 101;
    // The value of h would be "pow(d, M-1)%q"  
    for (i = 0; i < M - 1; i++)
        h = (h * d) % q;

    // Calculate the hash value of pattern and first  
    // window of text  
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        p = (d * p + pat[i]) % q;
        t = (d * t + text[i]) % q;
    }

    // Slide the pattern over text one by one  
    for (i = 0; i <= N - M; i++)
    {

        // Check the hash values of current window of text  
        // and pattern. If the hash values match then only  
        // check for characters on by one  
        if (p == t)
        {
            /* Check for characters one by one */
            for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {
                if (text[i + j] != pat[j])
                    break;
            }

            // if p == t and pat[0...M-1] = txt[i, i+1, ...i+M-1]  
            if (j == M)

            return i;
        }

        // Calculate hash value for next window of text: Remove  
        // leading digit, add trailing digit  
        if (i < N - M)
        {
            t = (d * (t - text[i] * h) + text[i + M]) % q;//   <---- warning is here 

[i + M


            // We might get negative value of t, converting it  
            // to positive  
            if (t < 0)
                t = (t + q);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

[context for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KchV.png)

Comment: post the error /warning in the question please, not a screenshot

Comment: @1201 `d` is `#define d 256` at the very top. Wish it were all caps with a more descriptive name, but here we are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding two `int` which is 4 bytes in your case, whereas `std::string::size_type` is probably 8 bytes in your case. Said conversion happens when you do:

```
 text[i + M]
```

Which is a call to [`std::string::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) taking a `std::string::size_type` as parameter.

Use `std::string::size_type`, which is usually the same as `size_t`.

gcc does not give any warning for that, even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, so I guess you activated really every warning you can, or something similar