# Arithmetic overflow warning

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following bit of code (`nsections` is defined as an `int`):

```
pipe_def.p_atamb     = new double[pipe_def.nsections+1];
```

I get this warning:

> Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then
> casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type
> before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2).

What type should `x` be in `new double array(x)` – `int` or `int64`?  (I thought `int`.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569147/c26451-arithmetic-overflow-using-operator-on-a-4-byte-value-then-casting-th

Comment: Side note: I bet this should be (instead) `pipe_def.p_atamb = std::make_unique<double[]>(pipe_def.nsections + 1);` (with `nsections` as a `std::size_t` and `p_atamb` as a `std::unique_ptr<double[]>`).

Comment: Is there a reason why `nsections` is not unsigned?

Comment: no reason other than that I am a Fortran programmer, and every now and then I need to write some C/C++ to interface to Fortran, there are no unsigned integers in Fortran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count (dimension) argument for the `new[]` operator is of `size_t` type, not `int`. On your platform (which appears to be MSVC, targeting 64-bit architecture), that `size_t` type is an `unsigned long long` (8 bytes). Hence the warning.

You can silence this warning by casting either of the operands of the addition:

```cpp
pipe_def.p_atamb = new double[static_cast<size_t>(pipe_def.nsections) + 1];
```

Or, if you are compiling to the C++23 Standard, you can use the [integer literal suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for the `size_t` type on the constant:

```cpp
pipe_def.p_atamb = new double[pipe_def.nsections + 1zU];
```

(Prior to C++23, you *could* use the `uLL` suffix but that will become platform-dependent, because the `size_t` type for 32-bit builds is only a 4-byte `unsigned long`.)

Answer (score 2):

> What type should `x` be in `new double[x]` ? `int` or `int64`? I thought int.

It should be (or will anyway be converted to) `std::size_t`.

- [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Explanation)

  > If *type* is an array type, all dimensions other than the first must be specified as ... type `std::size_t` (since C++14) ... [or] ... any expression convertible to `std::size_t` (since C++14)
- Standard: [[expr.new]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#8)

  > If the `expression` in a *noptr-new-declarator* is present, it is implicitly converted to `std​::​size_­t`.